# application doens't read config file when executed in debug vs ctrlf5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, app-config

I have a .net core application , that at some point in the project refers to another .netStandard DLL which reads from app.config file using:

`var x=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EngineServiceScansApiUrl"]`.

When I execute the application in debug mode (with debugger attached) x is null (the application can't find the configuration), whereas if I execute in ctrlf5 , sometimes it manages to read the configuration file, and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core uses appsettings.json instead of app.config. Take a look at this [article](https://ballardsoftware.com/adding-appsettings-json-configuration-to-a-net-core-console-application/) for more information. `ConfigurationManager` is not available in .NET Standard 2.0 without a NuGet package.

Comment: But it doesn't explain why it works part of the time and part of the time it doesn't

Comment: Right client on App.config > Properties and tell us what is the value of `Copy to Output Directory`